# Error when target text box on vba userform is not populated

Tags: excel, vba

I have no need to populate the search box when submitting guest check in details, the code i am using is below, is it possible to ad additional code to avoid this error. Thanks in advance!!!!!  lblrow.Caption = .Row 'error line

```
Private Sub Txtforename_Change()
    Dim rng As Range
    lblrow.Visible = False

    With Sheets("Report")
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))
    End With

    With rng.Find(Txtguestsearch, lookat:=xlWhole)
        lblrow.Caption = .Row
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Which error in which line? Please [edit] your original question and add the missing information.

Comment: That `FIND` statement will throw errors if a value in `Txtguessearch` isn't found.  If you expect it to be blank you could test `If Trim(Txtguestsearch) = "" Then`.  `Rng` may be better set as `Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))`.

Comment: lblrow.Caption = .Row 'error line

Comment: I want to try that tool, just don't have a personal windows (stupid millennial with a mac) and I can't put rubberduck on my work station in case you try to hack my screen and report that I spend 30% of my workday on **Stack Overflow**  @MathieuGuindon (*I'm on to you*)

Comment: @urdearboy - "stupid millennial with a mac" is one of the greatest quotes I've seen all year! Thanks for the laugh. Also, you won't be the only one in trouble for spending too much time at SO/SE!

Answer (score 3):

You need to code for possibility of your value not being found with the `Range.Find` method. 
I also updated your `LRow` calculation to use the with block and more standard calc

```
Private Sub Txtforename_Change()

Dim rng As Range, Found as Range
lblrow.Visible = False

With Sheets("Report")
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With

Set Found = rng.Find(Txtguestsearch, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not Found is Nothing Then
    With Found
        lblrow.Caption = .Row
    End With
Else                          '<--Optional
    MsgBox "Not Found"        '<--Optional
End If                      

End Sub
```

Comment: Sweeet, many thanks problem solved, removed the msgbox as not required.  Simply needed to allow guests check-in without experiencing the error. Cheers!!!!

Comment: @user3126785 notice the `.` dot operator in the `Set rng = .Range(...)` assignment - that's another bug this answer fixed in your code. Try running the original code with any other sheet than "Report" active - the unqualified `Range` call would fail, because it's implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet`.